# Django migration already applied but I don't have the migration file

Tags: python, django

A migration was applied to the database, and the table "blacklist_id" exists (and is populated with rows.)

I want to add a new Model and make a migration, but whenever I call makemigrations Django thinks that the blacklist_id model is new and attempts to make a migration for that, which causes an error.

I don't want to remove the table from the server because it has data in it - what can I do?

Comment: Option 1 (short term): Find the newest migration file and manually remove the section for the blacklist_id table
Option 2: In the django_migrations table artificially create an entry for the blacklist_id table creation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit odd that the table was created without having migration file created originally, but I'm assuming the table was created outside of Django or maybe the file was deleted accidentally.

The solution that may help is to create migrations for this specific app containing `blacklist_id` (e.g: `python manage.py makemigrations blacklist_app`)

Then apply fake migrations: `python manage.py migrate --fake`

This will simply create the migration file then mark it as made, without actually creating changes to database (*More on that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake)*)

Second workaround *(and it's not so pretty)* is to create another class, having the exact same fields as the `blacklist_id` table but with a different name (You can create it anywhere even in a separate app), then `makemigrations` and then edit the migration file to change the name of the table, and finally inject this migration file (Or just the operation of `migrations.CreateModel(...)`) inside your app, and finally use `migrate --fake` again, so it would be added in your migrations, and marked as performed, without any change in your database.